# Remove some CSS only if JS is supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 Divs that I would like to insert a class into ONLY if Javascript is not supported.

So consider this.. one Div has this `class="no-js-left"` and the other has this `class="no-js-right"`

What is the most simple way of detecting this and either removing these is JS is support something without using Modernizr?

Also I am using jQuery if that means anything

Comment: why the "without using modernizer"?

Comment: Isn't Modernizr a JavaScript library? How could you use it to detect that JavaScript is not supported when it won't work itself without JavaScript? You need to do it the other way around, like BoltClock's answer (with or without jQuery).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without JavaScript, your markup will remain static. For this to work, you'll have to add the classes to your HTML first, and then remove those classes using JavaScript.

Since you're using jQuery, you can easily take them out with [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass):

```
$('.no-js-left, .no-js-right').removeClass('.no-js-left .no-js-right');
```

Comment: this will just remove the classes and not hide/remove the divs

Comment: @Virendra: That's what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider using the root elements class name and different CSS selectors like this example:

```
<html class="js-disabled">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className = "js-enabled";
    </script>
```

and

```
.js-enabled .something { /* ... */ }
.js-disabled .something { /* ... */ }
```

This solution has a couple of advantages over BoltClocks answer:

1. It's actually faster, because it gets evaluated at the same time as the rendering of your page
2. You don't depend on jQuery if you want to drop it later ;-)
3. I would rather have `.js-disabled .something` than `.js-disabled-something` (personal preference though)

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code. If JavaScript is supported by the browser the below code will execute and hide the divs with classes `no-js-left` and `no-js-right`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.no-js-left').hide();
    $('.no-js-right').hide();
});
```

This code will just hide the divs and not actually remove them.

If you want to delete the divs from the page use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.no-js-left').remove();
    $('.no-js-right').remove();
});
```

**Update**:
If you want to just remove the classes then use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.no-js-left').removeClass('.no-js-left');
    $('.no-js-right').removeClass('.no-js-right');
});
```

Comment: The question is about removing the classes from the divs, not removing or hiding the divs themselves.